# Binary Search tree (BST) Question: is every node in the right subtree of a value and key both greater than the root?

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm reading the definition of Binary Search Tree (BST) on Algorithms, 4th Edition Princeton, and their definition is this:

> A binary search tree (BST) is a binary tree where each node has a
> Comparable key (and an associated value) and satisfies the restriction
> that the key in any node is larger than the keys in all nodes in that
> node's left subtree and smaller than the keys in all nodes in that
> node's right subtree.

My question is: Is a value of a key follows the same rule of the key, i.e. smaller than its right subtree node value and greater than its left subtree node value. I've searched related questions but not found a specific answer. My instinction tells me that it should be both follow that rule. But when I read their implementation in java, I get confused.

This is the code for implementing the input a node for BST

```
private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val) {
        if (x == null) return new Node(key, val, 1);
        int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);
        if      (cmp < 0) x.left  = put(x.left,  key, val);
        else if (cmp > 0) x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
        else              x.val   = val;
        x.size = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
        return x;
    }
```

We can see that the programmer only compares the key of the new input object but not the value. So basically I can enter a node that its key is less than its parent node but its value is greater than its parent node.

(
the Algorithms web is https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/
the code for implementation is https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/32bst/BST.java.html
)

Comment: The values don't matter at all. They could even be objects that are not comparable at all. They keys only matter in how the nodes are ordered in the tree.

Comment: As @user1984 implied, a BST just manages keys.  Nodes can contain only keys. In that case the BST implements a set (actually a sorted set).  Alternately, the nodes can contain both key and value(s). Here the keys are used to quickly locate any node or to traverse all nodes in key comparison order. Every time a key is processed (located or traversed), the values are there for free.  The BST is implementing a sorted map.

Comment: Thank you guys. Now I understand. "key is used to quickly locate something I want to find, and I can store many things in BST as values"